# How to check whether Alert Dialog is open in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am working on my flutter application and I want to check whether the alert dialog is open or not on the screen .
Can anyone tell me how to do that, basically I want to do some stuff just before and after alert dialog opens and closes.

Answer (score 48):

you can use this method:

```
_isThereCurrentDialogShowing(BuildContext context) =>
  ModalRoute.of(context)?.isCurrent != true;
```

Comment: perfect solution..

Comment: can you please explain? thanks

Comment: @Ritunjaykumar when alert is displayed it is actually a new route being pushed to the screen which means that current route is not the one that is behind but alert window.

Comment: great man . god bless u .. great answer

Answer (score 14):

First thing is you will be showing dialog yourself. So, you can use a `bool` value to track it.

Like this.

```
bool _isDialogShowing = false;

void _showDialog() {
  _isDialogShowing = true; // set it `true` since dialog is being displayed
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text("Title"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("CANCEL"),
            onPressed: () {
              _isDialogShowing = false; // set it `false` since dialog is closed
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

To listen for back button, you can wrap your root widget in `WillPopScope` and handle things in `onWillPop()` accordingly.

Comment: I am not using any cancel button in my alert , so how do I check that alert is poped up? and could you please explain me about WillPopScope more?

Comment: You can do it using `showGeneralDialog` and put `dismissible` property to `false`, using this will ensure you that you are the only one who is handling pop up, like in your any action buttons in dialog.

Comment: I don't want any action button in my dialog.

Comment: OK, can you tell me your use case then? I will be able to assist you better.

Comment: so I want to add a frosted glass background behind my alert , so what i want to do is before pushing alert dialog i want to change my screen to frosted glass bg and then after poping up alert i want to remove that bg using setState .That's why I want to listen to the alert  dialog. Hope this all makes sense to you! Thanks !

Comment: OK, that makes sense, now how are you poping up the dialog?

Comment: By touching the space around the alert ( Modal Barrier) it automatically gets pop as I am not setting dismissible property .

Comment: with all due respect, a bool flag? Is this all we can come up with?

Comment: @最白目 yes it's a flag to keep track of dialog visibility.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad tha main problem is the back button and you put the solution without that?

Comment: @bl4ckr0se Simply override back button using `WillPopScope` and change bool value in it.

Comment: Make it static and not private: static bool isDialogShowing = false; To track dialog across the app.

Answer (score 12):

Add a key property in your widget:

```
 final GlobalKey _alertKey = GlobalKey();
```

Then assign the key to your alert dialog:

```
AlertDialog(
        key: _alertKey,
        .........
)
```

and later:

```
 if (_alertKey.currentContext != null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

Means if a `context` is attached to the key, the alert dialog is shown. you can use this approach in your stateless and stateful widgets.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, cool.

Comment: THANK YOU! i was going crazy trying to figure this out it should have been way simpler than this it's such a common use case.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. Maybe my solution would do any better for someone:

```
_isOpen = true;
showDialog(
    context: context,
    child: AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Some title!"),
      content: Text("Some content!"),
    )).then((_) => _isOpen = false);
```

The `then` will run when the alert closes.

Comment: the problem is that the user can dismiss the AlertDialog with back button.

Comment: Yes, and still the "then" will run after it

Answer (score 6):

try this !!!

```
Future _dialog;

_checkAndShowDialog() async {

    if (_dialog == null) {
      _dialog = showMyDialog();
      await _dialog;
      _dialog = null;
    } else {
     //do nothing
    }

}

//dialog should return future
Future showMyDialog() {
    return showDialog(
        context: _context,
        child: Container(child: Text("I am dialog"),) );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case its better to use a full screen dialog then u can create frosted glass effect and in center u can add alert box like container and decorate it. To make modal barier like effect wrap outter frosted glass container with inkWell or gesture detector and on tap pop the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the alert dialog to a variable and use the build method to populate it. Later check the variable to know whether the dialog is being shown or not.

Answer (score 0):

"so I want to add a frosted glass background behind my alert , so what i want to do is before pushing alert dialog i want to change my screen to frosted glass bg and then after poping up alert i want to remove that bg using setState .That's why I want to listen to the alert dialog. Hope this all makes sense to you! Thanks !"

This is what you responded as the purpose of your dialog.

You can await a dialog like this:

```
<do setup code here>

await showDialog(...);

<do final code here>
```

Regardless of how you show the dialog I don't see a flaw on this. If you don't have this on an `async` function you can always call `.then` and do stuff there:

```
<do setup code here>

showDialog(...).then((_) => <do final code here>);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer

```
final isDlg = ModalRoute.of(context).runtimeType == DialogRoute;
```